# What is the difference between sys and os.sys

Tags: python

What is the difference between `sys` and `os.sys` in python? I have seen many projects using `sys` when they have imported `os`. When I tried `dir(sys)` and `dir(os.sys)` they had same functions and their output was same.

I often see code using `sys.exit` like this, rather than using `os.sys.exit`, but both do the same thing.

```
import os   
import sys    
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`os.sys` is `os`'s "private" name for `sys`; Python does not hide imports performed in another module. You should not depend on its existence, and should instead import `sys` directly yourself.